# Send async e-mails

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvcmailer

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3 with MVCMailer, I tried to send e-mails using SendAsync, but actually it still take longer.

So I am trying to use Task.Factory like the code bellow:

```
   var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(
            state =>
            {
                var mail = new UserMailer();
                var msg = mail.Welcome("My Name", "myemail@gmail.com");
                msg.SendAsync(); 
            });

   task1.Wait();
```

The problem is, MVCMailer needs HttpContext, but inside this task I got HttpContext Null.

How can I send Async e-mails?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A small addition to this.  Here is an extension method to help some.

```
using Mvc.Mailer; 
using System.Threading.Tasks;
public static void SendEmailAsync(this MvcMailMessage msg, HttpContext currContext)
{
      //make this process a little cleaner
      Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
      {
           System.Web.HttpContext.Current = currContext;
           msg.SendAsync();
       });
}
```

Use it like follows from your controller methods.

```
Mailers.UserMailer um = new Mailers.UserMailer();
um.SendWelcomeEmail(dataObject).SendEmailAsync(ControllerContext.HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Context);
```

Comment: Hey Matt! thanks for the reference, this looks great, does it send it asyncronously 100%, I've heard people say the MVCMailer one was pseudo async haha. Thanks mate!

Comment: No prob! I was banging my head against the desk for a bit with this one :)

Comment: Having `HttpContext` on two threads at the same time is dangerous and unsupported by ASP.NET.

Answer (score 4):

`Task.Factory.StartNew` will create a new thread.
If you want to access **HttpContext** which is in the main thread you have to do this:

```
var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current = ControllerContext.HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Context;
    var mail = new UserMailer();
    var msg = mail.Welcome("My Name", "myemail@gmail.com");
    msg.SendAsync();
    });

task1.Wait();
```

There a long debate if it's better to use TPL or QueueUserWorkItem.
Someone has tried to address the [issue](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/10/06/9903475.aspx).
This is the QueueUserWorkItem version:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private AutoResetEvent s_reset = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var state = new WorkerState() { HttpContextReference = System.Web.HttpContext.Current };
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(EmaiSenderWorker), state);

        try
        {
        s_reset.WaitOne();
        }
        finally
        {
        s_reset.Close();
        }

        return View();
    }

    void EmaiSenderWorker(object state)
    {
        var mystate = state as WorkerState;

        if (mystate != null && mystate.HttpContextReference != null)
        {
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current = mystate.HttpContextReference;
        }

        var mail = new UserMailer();
        var msg = mail.Welcome();
        msg.SendAsync();

        s_reset.Set();
    }

    private class WorkerState
    {
        public HttpContext HttpContextReference { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes LeflyX! I already tried this, but I don't know if is possible to pass the context variable to MVCMailer object.

Comment: @MichelAndrade: I have updated my answer. Try to see if it helps.

Comment: LeflyX, Almost there, if I take off "task1.Wait();" it does not work

Comment: @MichelAndrade: It does for me. Are you creating a new Task in a loop? I would suggest you to read this: http://www.codethinked.com/net-40-and-systemthreadingtasks

Comment: @LeflyX: Do you mind to take a look in my code?
http://codepaste.net/7acz6u

I'm not using Async Control, is there any problem?

Comment: No problem, sorry to boring you. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MichelAndrade: No problem. 50% of your question have answers not accepted. Help the others sometimes.

Comment: Having `HttpContext` on two threads at the same time is dangerous and unsupported by ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need tasks. SendAsync is asynchronous and use another thread self. Tasks dont accelerate you mailing.

**UPDATE**: 
When i resolve same problem i use task and synchronous send. It seems that SendAsync was not so asynchrous. It is sample of my code (it is not want HttpContext):

```
public void SendMailCollection(IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string, MailAddress>> mailParams)
    {
        var smtpClient = new SmtpClient
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_configurationService.SmtpUser, _configurationService.SmtpPassword),
            Host = _configurationService.SmtpHost,
            Port = _configurationService.SmtpPort.Value
        };

        var task = new Task(() =>
                                {
                                    foreach (MailMessage message in mailParams.Select(FormMessage))
                                    {
                                        smtpClient.Send(message);
                                    }

                                });
        task.Start();
    }

    private MailMessage FormMessage(Tuple<string, string, MailAddress> firstMail)
    {
        var message = new MailMessage
            {
                From = new MailAddress(_configurationService.SmtpSenderEmail, _configurationService.SmtpSenderName),
                Subject = firstMail.Item1,
                Body = firstMail.Item2
            };
        message.To.Add(firstMail.Item3);
        return message;
    }
```

Comment: Kirill, why it take to longer? I need send e-mail in the background.

Comment: Asynchronous is not means fast. It means that your slow process will not block your base thread and your application will react on user actions

Comment: Sure, but when I send emails, the process is block by this task.

Comment: BTW, i find my own code to resolve same problem, i used tasks too. I update my answer with sample of my code (it is not need HttpContext)

Answer (score 0):

```cs
public class UserMailer : MailerBase    
{
    RegisterService Service = new RegisterService();
    HttpContext Context;
    public UserMailer(HttpContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
        MasterName="_Layout";
    }

    public void ConfirmRegistration(Register model)
    {
        SendAsync(() =>
        {
            model.Conference = Service.Context.Conferences.Find(model.ConferenceID); // load conference bcs it fails to lazy load automatically.
            ViewData.Model = model;
            return Populate(x =>
            {
                x.Subject = "You registered for " + model.Conference.Name + "!"; ;
                x.ViewName = "Confirm";
                x.To.Add(model.Email);
            });
        });
    }

    private void SendAsync(Func<MvcMailMessage> GetEmail)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current = Context;
            GetEmail().Send();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer! While a code snippet could answer the question it's still great to add some addition information around, like explain, etc ..